# (cannot convert type void to string)

Tags: c#

I tried very hard, googled a lot but still I'm getting the same error.. Don't know what to change or how to change.
The error happens at `string std = Console.Write(p);`
I did assigned `p` to `hi` then why it returns to void..?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string p = "hi";
            string str = " if (p == ";
            string std = Console.Write(p);
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", str + std);
            string txt = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(txt); 
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting an out put like a text file with `if (p == hi` in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a *typo* in your code:

```
  ...
  string p = "hi";
  string str = " if (p == ";

  Console.Write(p); // just write, Console.Write returns void (i.e. nothing)

  File.WriteAllText("test.txt", str + p); // "+ p" not "+ std"
  string txt = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
  Console.WriteLine(txt); 
  ...
```

Comment: So.. Help me clear it a minute.. If i type "console.write(p);" and add p in the txt write .. "Hi" will be typed along with "(p=="...   Right?

Comment: @Revanth: if you want `"if (p == hi"` string as a result you have to combine `str` (`" if (p == "`) and `p` (`"hi"`). Compiler is developer's friend - if it says `"...cannot convert void to string..."` it means just what it means - `Console.Write(...)` returns `void` (*nothing*) which can't be converted into `string` in order to be assigned to `string std`

Comment: @Revanth: if you type "console.write(p);" you just output `p` value (which is `"hi"`) on the console. Nothing more. You will see `"hi"` on the console window, If you want to print out `"if (p == hi"`, just do it: `Console.Write(str + p); `

Comment: thank you bro..  i owe you..

Comment: And another thing..  Like.. Is there any command to say if i run a program and at the end of that program if i want to trigger another program.. So that first one will continue with the second one without any manual interpretation..  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[`Console.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/testw4x7(v=vs.110).aspx) does not return any value and hence you can't assign result of than call.

Note that to specify "no return value" in C# special `void` return type is used which leads to error you see (explanation in italic):

> "can't assign `void` *(result of `Console.Write`)* to `string` *(type of `std` variable)*" .

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are getting at

```
string std = Console.Write(p);
```

is caused by the return Type of the Write Method: "void" (aka "nothing at all"). **Console.Write** only outputs its parameters into your Console Application.